# PhP constructor and chaining

Tags: php, method-chaining

recently I checked out the SwiftMailer package, and found this problem I cannot explain:

```
// #1
$message = new Swift_Message($subject)->setFrom($f)->setTo($t)->setBody($body);

// #2
$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($f)->setTo($t)->setBody($body);

// #3
$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($f);
$message->setTo($t);
$message->setBody($body);
```

Variant #1 is from the SwiftMailer docs, and does not work, it gives a "unexpected '>'" parse error. The issue was easy to resolve, variant #2 and #3 work perfectly.

I thought that method chaining was a widely used technique in PHP, and I also thought that #1 was perfectly valid. Why doesn't it work as expected?

My PHP is V7.1.1

Thx, Armin.

Comment: Change it to this `(new Swift_Message($subject))->setFrom($f)->setTo($t)->setBody($body);`

Comment: What documentation did you get #1 from? I looked in https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html and it shows the syntax that @SahilGulati uses.

Comment: Case #1 was never valid syntax. I doubt you find it in the documentation of SwiftMailer.

Comment: to be honest, i would stick with #2 or #3 - #1 just doesn't look right to me, even if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example number one is not written as such in the docs, none of the examples method chain of a class instantiation as that has never been valid PHP.

The documentation instead is written as such:

```
// Create the message
$message = (new Swift_Message())

    // Give the message a subject
    ->setSubject('Your subject')

    // Set the From address with an associative array
    ->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])

    // Set the To addresses with an associative array (setTo/setCc/setBcc)
    ->setTo(['receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'])

    // Give it a body
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself')

    // And optionally an alternative body
    ->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')

    // Optionally add any attachments
    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'));
```

Notice that the class is instantiated within enclosing brackets. This allows for method chaining directly from the constructor.

Comment: Sometimes it's the easy things :-) Thanks! And the "original" docs are correct too, I was unlucky to run into a faulty web-formatted copy at first hand.